# Any cross-platform video playback library for c++?

Tags: c++, qt, video, playback, phonon

I mainly code using the Qt library, which is cross-platform enough for my need. However, I found out that if I'd like to play a video file there are no good options for cross-platform video playback. The Phonon module doesn't seem to work on my machine and I am not sure if it is supported on the major platforms (Windows, OSX, Linux).

Are their any light-weight alternatives for simple video playback? I would be okay to change my video to any format as long as its playable cross-platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [Theora playback library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libtheoraplayer/) to be very useful and only depends on the original theora library. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/theora-player/) is a simple Qt project I made that encapsulate everything needed to play (only video) theora media. You just type 'qmake' and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I am considering libVLC as one option. Someone have already made a [wrapper](https://github.com/ntadej/vlc-qt) but it only supports Windows and Linux.

Comment: the `wrapper` library happens to be GPL code... careful if you intend to use this wrapper for commercial purposes or if you dont intend to publish the code for it under GPL when you choose to distribute it, as the GPL requires...

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation is appears Phonon needs third party libraries to work correctly. Have you installed the appropriate backend to the platform you're on?

From the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/phonon-overview.html):

> **Backends**
>
> The multimedia functionality is not implemented by Phonon itself, but
>   by a back end - often also referred to as an engine. This includes
>   connecting to, managing, and driving the underlying hardware or
>   intermediate technology. For the programmer, this implies that the
>   media nodes, e.g., media objects, processors, and sinks, are produced
>   by the back end. Also, it is responsible for building the graph, i.e.,
>   connecting the nodes. *The backends of Qt use the media systems
>   DirectShow (which requires DirectX) on Windows, QuickTime on Mac, and
>   GStreamer on Linux.* The functionality provided on the different
>   platforms are dependent on these underlying systems and may vary
>   somewhat, e.g., in the media formats supported.
>
> Backends expose
>   information about the underlying system. It can tell which media
>   formats are supported, e.g., AVI, mp3, or OGG.
>
> A user can often add
>   support for new formats and filters to the underlying system, by, for
>   instance, installing the DivX codex. We can therefore not give an
>   exact overview of which formats are available with the Qt backends.

Comment: I tried Phonon on my other machine and it worked directly. I think the broken machine had issues with audio device. Still, I think I will try it on more devices and see.

Answer (score 0):

[QtWebKit 2.2](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKitFeatures22) has support for HTML5 media. It should (at least eventually) be pretty cross-platform, but probably has the same backend issues as Phonon. But a `Q(Graphics)WebView` with a `<video>` element could do the trick for a truly play-and-forget solution.

Comment: Have you tried it on different platforms? I will give it a shot and see what happens. My other option would be 'libvlc' I found a library out there 'VLC-Qt' but haven't tried it.